# mapMonadTrans :: MonadTrans xT => (m a -> n b) -> xT m a -> xT n b

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

The problem is this. I have:

```
f :: MonadIO m => ReaderT FooBar m Answer;
f = (liftIO getArgs) >>= ...
```

I need to run this with modified arguments. However, since m is unknown, I cannot simply use

```
mapReaderT (withArgs args) :: ReaderT r IO b -> ReaderT r IO b
```

since I need somehow to transform (withArgs args) into m for all m.

One possibility I found is to define my own withArgs, thus:

```
import System.Environment (setArgs, freeArgv);
withArgv new_args act = do {
  pName <- liftIO System.Environment.getProgName;
  existing_args <- liftIO System.Environment.getArgs;
  bracket (liftIO $ setArgs new_args)
          (\argv -> do {
                      _ <- liftIO $ setArgs (pName:existing_args);
                      liftIO $ freeArgv argv;
                    })
          (const act);
};

withArgs xs act = do {
  p <- liftIO System.Environment.getProgName;
  withArgv (p:xs) act;
};
```

However, this is a kludge, and specific to one function -- I would need to re-write every `withX :: X -> IO a -> IO a`, e.g. Control.Exception.handle

What, if any, is a better way to do this?

Edit: In the case of handle, I found Control.Monad.CatchIO. In the other case, I used yet another, briefer kludge (not worth posting) to avoid the kludge above. Still seeking a better solution!

Comment: What if you remove the type signature on `f`? I wonder if constraining to `MonadIO` is too restrictive.

Comment: I need to do I/O in `f`. Otherwise, that would be grand. (In reality, I have a data type a with a function in it to yield some value of type b, and the function must be general enough so that some values of type a can do I/O to yield b.)

Comment: @strake: note that there's a problem with Control.Monad.CatchIO.  Namely, if you're using a short-circuiting monad transformer (e.g. ErrorT) it's possible for it to not behave as you expect.  Whether this is a design flaw or misuse is open to interpretation, but you should be aware of it.  See http://andersk.mit.edu/haskell/monad-peel/ for details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [monad-control](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/monad-control) package will do this.  I think you want the function `liftIOOp_` from [Control.Monad.IO.Control](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/monad-control/0.2.0.1/doc/html/Control-Monad-IO-Control.html).

Specifically,

```
liftIOOp_ (withArgs newArgs) f
```

should do what you want.  You can lift things like `bracket` too, with the `liftIOOp` function.

Answer (score 9):

Part of what you are looking for is a hoisting of a monad homomorphism into a monad transformer.

```
class MonadHoist t where
    hoist :: (Monad m, Monad n) => (forall a. m a -> n a) -> t m a -> t n a

    t :: Monad m => t Identity a -> t m a
    t = hoist (return . runIdentity)
```

That is to say, given a monad homomorphism `f` from `m` to `n`, you can obtain a monad homomorphism from `t m` to `t n` using hoist.

A monad homomorphism is slightly stronger than the types above enforce, namely it is responsible for preserving the monad laws.

```
f . return = return
f . fmap g = fmap g . f
f . join = join . f . fmap f
         = join . fmap f . f -- by the second law
         = (>>= f) . f       -- >>= in terms of join
```

Notice the quantifier that I snuck in the type of `hoist`, `MonadHoist` turns out to need that flexibility for almost all instances! (`Reader` happens to be the one case where it doesn't. Try to write MaybeT without it.)

Monad transformers can, in general, instantiate this class. For instance:

```
instance MonadHoist (StateT s) where
    hoist f (StateT m) = StateT (f . m)

instance MonadHoist (ReaderT e) where
    hoist f (ReaderT m) = ReaderT (f . m)

instance MonadHoist MaybeT where
    hoist f (MaybeT m) = MaybeT (f m)
```

We don't currently provide it in `transformers` or `mtl` package because it would require a `Rank2Type`, but it is pretty straightforward to implement.

If there is enough demand for it, I'll happily package it up in a `monad-extras` package.

Now, I said part, because while this answers the question given by the type in the topic of your post, it doesn't address the need reflected by the bulk of the text associated with your question!

For that, you probably want to follow luqui's advice. =)

Comment: Good idea. Actually, (as I just noticed,) someone else realized it: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmtl

Answer (score 4):

I believe the [interleavableIO package](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/interleavableIO) addresses this problem.  It is discussed in [this cafe thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-July/028501.html).

Comment: It might, but, unfortunately, it's highly perplexing. How is it used?

Comment: @strake, Unfortunately, I've never used it, I just remembered it being discussed.  Maybe another SO question is in order?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use `runReaderT` to get the effect you want, as well:

```
*> :t withArgs [] (runReaderT f FooBar)
withArgs [] (runReaderT f FooBar) :: IO Answer
```

where `FooBar` is some data constructor and `f` is defined as above.